# Problem with the ical feed of the calendar

Tags: wordpress, civievent, calendar

I would really like to use CiviCRM's function to create an ical feed for the calendar. But I'm having some hard times to get it working.

The event has a title, a date, a custom category and a 'long description'. When you visit the url to the ical feed: https://example.tld/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fical&reset=1

you get the following .ics file

civicrm_ical.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviEvent iCal//EN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:CiviCRM_EventID_4_215ca88ba6fc880ae683205e6cd7bc8d@example.tld
SUMMARY:Test-event
DESCRIPTION:Some description
CATEGORIES:ALV
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190401T200000
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190401T200000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190402T030000
URL:https://example.tld/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=4
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

But when I use the url of the feed in fastmail or google calendar for instance, an error appears, or the calendar items do not appear. What could be the problem?

I use CiviCRM 5.10.3 on Wordpress.

Kind regards,

Sam

--- edit ---

I got the following error message from Fastmail, my mailprovider.

> Syncing to your [redacted] calendar has been disabled: [ad2278bd-7237-4dee-884f-4eff6f3666bc] The calendar data was invalid: Error parsing VCalendar data: error Closed a different card name than opened at line 7 char 0:
>
> ```
> ---> ï»¿BEGIN:VCALENDAR
> VERSION:2.0
> PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviEvent iCal//EN
> X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam
> METHOD:PUBLISH
> END:VCALENDAR
>  <--- at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/Text/VCardFast.pm line 55.
>
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
> VERSION:2.0
> PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviEvent iCal//EN
> X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam
> METHOD:PUBLISH
> END:VCALENDAR
>  at /home/mod_perl/hm/ME/CalDAVTalk.pm line 1427.
>     ME::CalDAVTalk::_getEventsFromVCalendar(ME::CalDAV=HASH(0x8601578), "\x{feff}BEGIN:VCALENDAR\x{a}VERSION:2.0\x{a}PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviE"...) called at /home/mod_perl/hm/ME/CalDAVTalk.pm line 2554
>     ME::CalDAVTalk::vcalendarToEvents(ME::CalDAV=HASH(0x8601578), "\x{feff}BEGIN:VCALENDAR\x{a}VERSION:2.0\x{a}PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviE"...) called at /home/mod_perl/hm/ME/CalDAV.pm line 1434
>     eval {...} called at /home/mod_perl/hm/ME/CalDAV.pm line 1433
>     ME::CalDAV::syncFromIcal(ME::CalDAV=HASH(0x8601578), "b8285308-2a18-4c47-9d22-fae8d8798d21", "\x{feff}BEGIN:VCALENDAR\x{a}VERSION:2.0\x{a}PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviE"..., HASH(0x89e5670), "Force", 0, "ReadUidPrefix", "913888i-") called at /home/mod_perl/hm/ME/CalDAV.pm line 1904
>     eval {...} called at /home/mod_perl/hm/ME/CalDAV.pm line 1867
>     ME::CalDAV::syncCalendar(ME::CalDAV=HASH(0x8601578), 913888, "Force", 0) called at /home/mod_perl/hm/scripts/caldav_sync.pl line 271
>     main::SyncCalendar(ME::User=HASH(0x89bea78)) called at /home/mod_perl/hm/scripts/caldav_sync.pl line 98
> ```

I have no idea what to make of this. There are currently no events in the calendar.

Comment: For google, it might just be a delay. For example if you import the file, as a file import not a feed, you need to then close google calendar and reopen it to see the event. The feed maybe takes its own time. See here where it says "add using a link" https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en&ref_topic=1672445. It says it might take 12 hours. When you say you get an error, what error do you get?

Comment: i don't seem to get an error no more. but also after several days the calendar items are not loading. am i missing something obvious? what do you make of the ical-feed and its url, they're alright, right?

Comment: It looks ok, and it does import into google as a file. A crazy workaround might be to set up the feed on your phone or somewhere where it does work, then set up that calendar to sync to the google calendar.

Comment: I just got the error from Fastmail. Do you have an idea what to make of it?

Comment: I got a response from Fastmail. The engineers there found out that the problem is the following:

"The problem is that your ics file begins with a UTF-8 Byte order mark or BOM — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Our server did not know what to do with this, but we've fixed it and now you should be all set.

I don't think it's typical to provide these in ics files, but we should have been able to handle it just the same."

So this seems to be an issue of CiviCRM, I opened an issue on their Gitlab: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/issues/25 .

Comment: That usually happens when you have an extension or maybe even your civicrm.settings.php file that contains a BOM, so it gets output from there. Use the `grep` listed here (not the `find`) to see if there is one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858757/8332458

Comment: See also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30482/ical-feed-doesnt-work-lots-of-public-events-but-none-found ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved with help I got on the civiCRM repo. (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/issues/25).

1. First I found two files in my site that are loaded on every page that contain a BOM.

`find . -type f -printf "%p " -a -exec od -x -N 4 \{\} \; | grep "bbef 3cbf"`

2. Secondly I removed those BOMs with vim.

Edit the files (which in my case where the `functions.php` and `header.php` file of my theme) with vim. Type `:set nobomb` and save the files.

Now I can use the ical url of my site and it will load in virtual calendars.

Comment: Ha ha you might not have noticed I'm the same person, the same way you have different usernames. No worries.

Comment: Haha, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/issues/25 and using a different grep since the grep linked to in the comments above doesn't seem to work, there were two theme files with a BOM.

This grep

`find . -type f -printf "%p " -a -exec od -x -N 4 \{\} \; | grep "bbef 3cbf"`

located

`wp-content/themes/ari/functions.php
wp-content/themes/ari/header.php`